# Single product, shared catalog, multiple stores, cannot assign a store_view different categories?

Tags: magento2, category, multistore

Interesting problem:

> Magento 2.1.10 CE

I have two websites that share the same root catalog, one store (StoreA) contains 2 store_views, and the other store (storeB) has a single store_view.

I have a single product that needs to be listed in ALL 3 store_views. However, in StoreB it also needs to be listed in a category that is only enabled for StoreB.

The problem I'm having is, if I change the category that the Product is assigned to in StoreB, it also updates and changes the Category for StoreA's individual Store_views. Someone told me that this is because Both Websites share the same root category, but I'm not 100% convinced of that.

Can anybody else confirm if this is true, or am I experiencing a bug?

Comment: I'm a little confused with your explanation but what it seems you are trying to accomplish is best handled with independent root categories. Product updates will still be reflected in both it just makes the management easier.

Comment: At this time, it is not really feasible to separate the root categories.  The basic gist is that I cannot change categories of a product at the store/store_view level, it seems to be doing it across both websites (and their respective store/store_views as well).  Is this because of the same root category, or something else?